# How do I debug a flask application from within emacs?

Tags: python, debugging, debug

I want to use something like pdbpp or ipdb to debug a flask application. I've tried but not understood how to set a breakpoint in a python file that's part of a wider application and see it hit. There appear to be dozens of examples of how to run a single file in a debugger in emacs, but that's not what I want to do.